# VSTO Outlook: duplicate a recipient but with a different email address

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I wonder if there is some way to create a new Outlook.recipient based on another, but using a different email address. is that possible? if so, how?

Comment: Not in Outlook Object Model.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The Outlook object model provides the [NameSpace.CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method which creates a `Recipient` object. The name of the recipient can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient, but not any other recipient.